# Getting attribute value using namespace and xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

```
<Product xmlns:fish="urn:fish.com:international">
      <Assets fish:relativePath="013\7614500010013">
      </Assets> 
</Product>
```

I need to be able to get at the asset attribute fish:relativePath with an xslt. How do I do this?

I've already put the fish namespace into the xslt header.

```
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:asp="remove" 
xmlns:fish="urn:fish.com:international">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a template for the Assets node that accesses the attribute using `@`, then apply that template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:asp="remove" 
                xmlns:fish="urn:fish.com:international">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/Product/Assets"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Assets">
    <xsl:value-of select="@fish:relativePath"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```